laravel 11. lorisleiva/laravel-actions. How to register command
How to register a command via action without using the Console/Kernel.php file, because it does not exist in Laravel 11.
I executed the command
composer requires laravel/tinker
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider"

and in config/tinker.php:
 'commands' => [
      \App\Actions\SitemapGenerateAction::class,
 ],

here is the action
 use AsAction, AsCommand;

 public string $commandSignature = 'sitemap:generate';
 public string $commandDescription = 'Generate the sitemap';

 protected array $sitemapData;

 public function handle(): void
 {
 ...
 }

 public function asCommand(Command $command): void
 {
 ...
 }

 public function asController(): array
 {
 ...
 }


I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know in case you have any issue.Thanks.


How to register a command via action without using the Console/Kernel.php file, because it does not exist in Laravel 11. I executed the command

In laravel 11 kernal.php is no longer present.And the configuration should be made through bootstrap/app.php file.
Task Scheduling,command registered is done through routes/console.php in laravel 11.
For more detailed information you can check this link where you can define your command in routes/console.php.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/artisan#closure-commands
And to get a crystal clear view on changes made on Laravel 11 you can check this link.
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-11-directory-structure
After going through above two mentioned link,I think you will get a clear idea about how you should register and use command
I have even answered a similar answer on this platform. You may chek it as well.
Laravel Kernel.php file alternative

Thanks for the answer. It worked:
->withCommands([
\App\Actions\SitemapGenerateAction::class,
])

If you follow the Laravel Actions reference here, there is this way to register all commands automatically
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            Actions::registerCommands();
        }
    }
}

I've tried it and it works on Laravel 11 :)
